# Kalman Filter for Android

Tags: android, game-physics

Is there a Kalman filter implementation I can use to fliter my gyroscope and acceleration data from an Android Phone?

Comment: I think [it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15657798/4832664) will be useful for implementation.

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at this project: http://library.rl-community.org/wiki/Helicopter_(Java)

They are using kalman filters for gyrosensors etc and it's java too ... you can download the source and probably use some of it pretty easy in android.

You should also check out [rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/plugins/kalman.html](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/plugins/kalman.html) and [www.vni.com/products/imsl/jmsl/v30/api/com/imsl/stat/KalmanFilterEx1.html](http://www.vni.com/products/imsl/jmsl/v30/api/com/imsl/stat/KalmanFilterEx1.html)

Happy hacking

Answer (score 6):

[This](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jkalman/) is an open source java implementation of Kalman filter. Maybe you could try to use it in your android project.