# iOS ways or tips to improve quality of GPS tracking

Tags: ios, algorithm, gps, tracking

As we all know tracking the position of a moving iOS device can be very handy. We have seen that in various sport/fitness applications. Due to the fact that sometimes the position determination gets inaccurate due to poor signal or other interferences I would like to ask if there are any common ways/tips/algorithms to achieve an almost seamless gps track?

I would be very thankful for any references?

Cheers,
anka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would actually seem like a problem more fit for a [Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter). In short: you make educated guesses based on the last known position and velocity, then update your guess when new data comes in. Uncertainty comes into play as well.

It doesn’t have to be just position/velocity, you can do this with any number of scalar variables.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good application for a [particle filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_filter).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Going form there i also found more on this topic over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134579/smooth-gps-data