# virtual sensor android

Tags: android, android-sensors

I came across a post in google forums which said Kalman filter is implemented in android Virtual sensor( http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17780     post#8) . But I didn't find anything mentioned about kalman filter in android documentation. So is it true that Kalman filter is implemented in the android API ? And where can I get the source code for the Virtual sensor (TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) ?

Answer (score 1):

If they're not using Kalman filters in their virtual sensors then they should be!  I posted a simple Kalman filter last month to answer the question "[Smooth GPS data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134579/smooth-gps-data/15657798)".  It's not the case that you've asked for, but if you haven't seen a Kalman filter before it might be a good place to start, because Kalman filters can be quite complex and filtering location data on Android is a simple example.