# Increasing the accuracy of proximity alerts in Android

Tags: java, android, location

My application keeps track of a user's location, and sets up proximity alerts for nearby stores returned by an API for an automatic-chickin type functionality. I'm hitting my head against the wall trying to figure out how to improve the accuracy when the proximity alert is triggered by network location. I need some way to confirm that the user is at the location by either checking again within a few minutes, or by confirming their current position via GPS.

Part of the issue is that the Context handling the proximity alert is an intent service, so anything that works asynchronously causes issues when the alerts fire in rapid succession. Clearly there's a way to do this properly (e.g. Google+ checkin notifications), but I'm at a loss as to where to look next.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that network location is often less accurate than GPS location, although neither is 100% reliable.  Sometimes GPS will be perfect, but at other times it's wrong my maybe 50 metres or more.  To handle the this, I think the best way is to combine the two location sources using a simple Kalman filter, so that neither network or GPS trigger promimity alerts directly, instead it's the result of the Kalman filtering that is used.  See my answer to [Smooth GPS data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134579/smooth-gps-data/15657798#15657798) for full details of a Kalman filter that might work.