# Location is not working in my app properly

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, locationmanager

Pasted below is my class for getting coordinates from user. But sometimes, I get latitude and longitud as null. I know this is because I have no network enough, or I'm inside a building, or whatever ... but the weird thing is that, in that moment, I go to Google Maps or other maps app, and the "geo locate me" button works perfectly.

What am I missing others don't ?

```
public class LocationActivity extends BaseActivity {

private LocationManager locationManager = null;

LocationListener onLocationChange=new LocationListener() 
{
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        LocalSession.lat = loc.getLatitude();
        LocalSession.lng = loc.getLongitude();
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(onLocationChange);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(onLocationChange);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,10000.0f,onLocationChange);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,10000.0f,onLocationChange);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You are getting NULL values in the location information that is because `GPS_PROVIDER` requires open sky for fetching location information.

If you use `NETWORK_PROVIDER` provider, you can have location information even inside the room as your device is getting Network Coverage inside the room.

The code you are using contains both provider,

```
try 
{
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,10000.0f,onLocationChange);
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,10000.0f,onLocationChange);
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Hence the second Provider ( GPS_PROVIDER )will replace the first one ( NETWORK_PROVIDER ) as you are using same LocationManager class's object.

My Suggestion is to use either of following way,

- Use NETWORK_PROVIDER
- Switch between two providers, i. e. if GPS_PROVIDER returns NULL then only try NETWORK_PROVIDER

Comment: Yes, @Lucifer is bang on target with his answer. check this [link for ref](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16393534/2345913)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use both NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER at the same time, feeding both results into a Kalman Filter using the code that I posted in my answer here: [Smooth gps data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134579/smooth-gps-data/15657798#15657798).  The more information that's used the better.  The Kalman filter methodology will be better IF the accuracy estimates of both GPS and the Network Provider are reliable, i.e. it doesn't matter if any of the estimates are unreliable as long as the accompanying accuracy specifies that.