# iOS GPS data issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to retrieve data from GPS, but it's not so accurate. Here is a screenshot :

[image: gpssc]

It worked great with GPS emulation on the simulator. I want to know how to improve this.

Here is the code I tried :

```
    UserLocation = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 60000
    [UserLocation setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically:NO];
    [UserLocation setActivityType:CLActivityTypeFitness];
#endif
   UserLocation.delegate = self;
    [UserLocation setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [UserLocation setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];
    [UserLocation startUpdatingLocation];
```

and then I retrieve data every second and check if it's different than the previous one.

Comment: where is screenshot??????

Comment: This is to be expected at times. GPS data in general will rarely be anywhere near 100% accurate. There are reflections from nearby buildings and other issues to deal with when reading raw GPS data. You'll want to look into a smoothing algorithm that can take the raw GPS data and intelligently interpret the results. Also, make sure that you toss away any data that does not meet the level of accuracy that you need.

Comment: then how to deal with these issues

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134579/smooth-gps-data) and see if it helps

Comment: can u add some code to explain your problem

Comment: hi user2381789, code added

Comment: [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:
     kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation]; try this code

Answer (score 2):

Ric Perrott is right about the GPS data never being 100% accurate all the time. I suggest you set your accuracy to kCLLocationAccuracyBest which according to Apple is the right setting for what you are trying to do.

To try and filter out some of the 'jumping' you are getting, I suggest taking an average reading. For example, take X number of GPS readings (5 or 10 or...) and then average out. This will eliminate the occasional incorrect reading your device might get.

I wrote a fitness walking app a while back and had similar issues. Averaging did not completely resolve the issue but it did smooth it out a lot.

Comment: Could you give me head start(code implementation) to average out the gap points?