# Dealing with imprecise, jittery gps signal

Tags: c#, android, gps, xamarin, xamarin.android

My goal is to use GPS to measure the distance that I moved with my phone. My problem is, that the results are imprecise. I've used the following code to calculate the distance:

```
public double getDistance(GeoCoordinate p1, GeoCoordinate p2)
{
    double d = p1.Latitude * 0.017453292519943295;
    double num3 = p1.Longitude * 0.017453292519943295;
    double num4 = p2.Latitude * 0.017453292519943295;
    double num5 = p2.Longitude * 0.017453292519943295;
    double num6 = num5 - num3;
    double num7 = num4 - d;
    double num8 = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(num7 / 2.0), 2.0) + ((Math.Cos(d) * Math.Cos(num4)) * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(num6 / 2.0), 2.0));
    double num9 = 2.0 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(num8), Math.Sqrt(1.0 - num8));
    return (6376500.0 * num9);
}
```

This is my `OnLocationChanged` implementation:

```
bool begin = true;

public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
{

    _aktuellerOrt = location;
    //aktuellerOrt.Speed is always 0, so I cannot use that.
    if (_aktuellerOrt == null)
    {
        //message
    }
    else
    {

        if (_aktuellerOrt.Accuracy > 70) //I found values around 130 to be more or less good
        {
            _locationText.Text = String.Format("{0}, {1}", _aktuellerOrt.Latitude, _aktuellerOrt.Longitude);
            GeoJetzt = new GeoCoordinate();
            GeoJetzt.Latitude = _aktuellerOrt.Latitude;
            GeoJetzt.Longitude = _aktuellerOrt.Longitude;
            if (beginn)
            {
                GeoVorher = new GeoCoordinate();
                GeoVorher.Latitude = _aktuellerOrt.Latitude;
                GeoVorher.Longitude = _aktuellerOrt.Longitude;
                beginn = false;
            }
            else
            {
                double abstand = getDistance(GeoVorher, GeoJetzt);
                weg += abstand;
                if (weg >= 1)
                    _distanzText.Text = weg + " kilometers";
                else
                    _distanzText.Text = (weg * 1000) + " meters";
                _distanzText.Text += " (" + abstand + ", " + _aktuellerOrt.Accuracy + ")";
                GeoVorher = new GeoCoordinate();
                GeoVorher.Latitude = _aktuellerOrt.Latitude;
                GeoVorher.Longitude = _aktuellerOrt.Longitude;
            }
        }
        else
            _locationText.Text = "Too coarse, now " + _aktuellerOrt.Accuracy + ".";
    }
}
```

The problem is, I get values for `abstand` within the kilometer range while not moving the phone.

What are best practices for imprecise signals? My goal is to measure the distance while jogging or running, so 10 - 16 km/h.

Comment: Walking isn't 10 km/h, it is more like 5 km/h (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walking_speed), anyways, you would use a low pass filter for that. You can try this Kalman filter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15657798/368379 and see if that works better.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Which value do you recommend for Q_metres_per_second?

Comment: Did you even read the text the guy provided? He made a lot of effort into creating that answer and even gives you an answer to what Q value to use.