# How to implement Kalman filter in Android with latitude and longitude?

Tags: android, kalman-filter, android-fusedlocation

Please help me with implementing Kalman Filter in my Android Code having current latitude, longitude, accuracy, timestamp and changed latitude, longitude on onLocationChanged.
If somebody could me help me with proper source code, it would be really great.

Tried this code :
[Kalman-filtered GPS data is still fluctuating a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738246/kalman-filtered-gps-data-is-still-fluctuating-a-lot)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you have tried. Does it work?

Comment: You should be more specific. Post the code you used and let us know what the issues are.