# App receives location updates when device is unmoving (rests)

Tags: android, geolocation, kalman-filter

I need to track device location in my app and draw it's route on the map. But I ran into a situation my geolocation service receives locations update even when the device is resting on the table. The resulting locations are always a little different from the original position and therefore I have unnecessary lines and figures on map drawn. I tried to receive location updates from [LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) and [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html), but the results of work are the same.
I tried to use [Kalman Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) to reduce the noise in the received data (I used these implementations: [KalmanLocationManager](https://github.com/villoren/KalmanLocationManager) and implementation from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134579/smooth-gps-data/15657798#15657798)), but results are still leave much to be desired.

How else can I improve the accuracy of location data and receive location updates only when device is really moving? Any help or advice appreciated

Thanks.