# Get rid of jumping GPS data with pykalman

Tags: python, matplotlib, gps, pykalman

I have gps data that I get from a smartphone application.
Whenever the smartphone is stationary, the gps points are jumping.
I understand that the signal is inaccurate due to the reception in a city between buildings and signal loss whenever inside.

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134579/smooth-gps-data) I wanted to give a shot to the Kalman filter.
Thanks to this [article](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/FlorianWilhelm/gps_data_with_python/blob/master/talk.ipynb) I was able to try out the Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm on the latitude and longitude, and try the [pykalman package](https://pykalman.github.io/) for the elevation data.
Also I have tried the [pykalman example](https://github.com/pykalman/pykalman/blob/master/examples/standard/plot_filter.py) to play with the filter.

According to these readings, I assume to have the wrong input parameters :

```
measurements = numpy.column_stack([longitude_list, latitude_list])
# F_k : state transition matrix
F = numpy.array([ [1, 0],
                  [0, 1] ])

# H_k : the observation matrix
H = numpy.array([ [1, 0],
                  [0, 1] ])

# R : covariance R of delta_k observation noise N(0, R)
R = numpy.diag([1e-4, 1e-4])

kf = kf.em(measurements, n_iter=100)
(filtered_state_means, filtered_state_covariances) = kf.filter(measurements)
(smoothed_state_means, smoothed_state_covariances) = kf.smooth(measurements)
```

The figures below are from matplotlib. The top left is with an iteration km.em(n_iter=2), top right with iteration 10, bottom left is iteration 50, bottom right is iteration 100. Whenever I try higher, I have a timeout. It does not seem that my filter work much on this case. Indeed the same shape is output (it might looks different at first because of the scale axis).

[image]

Am I missing something?
How can I improve my stationary gps jumping data?

Thank you

Comment: There is a GIS Exchange on here.  Lots of python users there. https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: oh thank you I was not aware of that. I may have my answers there .

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?